# Как управлять сессиями пользователей на сервере?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, сессия, foreach

На сайте регистрируются пользователи, заходят в пользовательскую часть сайта используя логин-пароль. В БД MySQL sessions пишутся активные сессии этих пользователей, чтобы подсчитывать сколько пользователей сейчас онлайн и других подобных целей.
Как получить доступ и управлять пользовательскими сессиями в PHP 5.6 ? Вот например я хочу получить доступ к данным сессии 7dkb0qepg9v84dg9nm5gn0c4t0, id которой хранится в моей таблице как это сделать?
И как держать актуальными данные в таблице sessions, чтобы она содержала только сессии пользователей, которые в данный момент на сайте? Может перебирать все сессии в цикле foreach, а в сессию каждому пользователю писать

> $_SESSION['last_access'] = time();

И затем

> foreach ($sessions_from_mysql_table as $session){ if( (time() -
>   $_SESSION['last_access']) > 120 )    // Delete session from mysql tbl
>   }

Как лучше сделать, подскажите. Сайт достаточно большой, пользователей > 160к

Comment: Разбивайте ваш вопрос на несколько точных и получаете конкретные ответы.Ото тут как правило не решают такие общие вопросы типа вот вам ТЗ, давайте ответ.

Comment: А зачем вам сессии в бд?

Comment: Я же написал "чтобы подсчитывать сколько пользователей сейчас онлайн и других подобных целей"